# How to find the sum of all elements of an NSMutableArray? Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, nsarray

So I'm trying to make an `NSMutableArray` that can update when another viewcontroller has inputted values.

This other viewcontroller is our "AddNewViewController."

**AddNewViewController.swift**

```
nameArray.add(namestring)

minutesArray.add(minutesint!)


print(nameArray)
print(minutesArray)


UserDefaults.standard.set(nameArray.mutableCopy(), forKey: "namearray")
UserDefaults.standard.set(minutesArray.mutableCopy(), forKey: "minutesarray")
UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
```

NameArray is irrelevant, uses an inputted string and adds that to our namearray.

The problem lies with `minutesArray`: I set an `Int` (`minutesint`) for `minutesArray`, which is inputted through a `UITextField` and converted into an int. This is then put into our `UserDefaults` for use in our other viewcontroller, `ViewController`

**ViewController.swift**

```
nameArray = UserDefaults.standard.mutableArrayValue(forKey: "namearray")
minutesArray = UserDefaults.standard.mutableArrayValue(forKey: "minutesarray")


let myCell = UITableViewCell()
myCell.textLabel?.text = ("Name: \(nameArray[indexPath.row] as! String)    Score (minutes): \(minutesArray[indexPath.row] as! Int)")

return myCell
```

I should clarify, that above is my cellForRowAt declaration. As you can see, it sets everything to our tableview just fine and dandy.

However, when I try and use tips from other questions such as using the "reduce" for an `NSArray` to sum all elements up I get this error from this piece of code:

```
let sumarray = minutesArray.reduce(0, +)
//Error: Ambiguous reference to member '+'
```

I realize that something is wrong with my formatting, because when I tested it with an immutable array like

```
let array = [1, 2 ,3]
let testarray = array.reduce(0, +)
print (testarray)
```

It gives me a nice, sexy print of 5?

When I checked the type that **array** is, it's apparently an `[Int]` type. However, I thought reduce was only possible to use on `Array`s?

What am I doing wrong?

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Just don't use `NSMutableArray`. Use native Swift `Array` – which is mutable for free as `var` – and the ambiguity goes away

Comment: … and multiple arrays as data source is strongly discouraged (, too).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read it as an int array `[Int]` instead

```
var minutesArray = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "minutesarray") as? [Int] ?? [Int]()
```